# Linear space language that requires exponential time without ETH

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, time-complexity, space-complexity, pspace

The $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{PSpace}$ conjecture means that

> There is a language $L \in \mathsf{DSpace}(O(n^t))$ for some $t>0$ such that for all positive integers $k$, $L$
>   requires $\Omega(n^k)$ deterministic time to decide.

But I need a stronger assumption

> There is a language in $\mathsf{DSpace}(O(n))$ that 
>   requires exponential ($2^{\Omega(n)}$) deterministic time  to decide.

Obviously the [Exponential Time Hypothesis (ETH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) implies the statement above: 
3SAT is in linear space.
But I don't want to assume ETH.

Is there a weaker conjecture (something that is plausible even if ETH is false) 
that I can use?

Comment: Why does $P \ne PSPACE$ give you (1) ? it could be that the language(s) separating P from PSPACE require $n^{10}$ space ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat, I guess a padded version of that language works (append $n^{10}$ zeroes to every string, the new language needs only linear space but is still not in $P$).

Comment: But @JeremyKun, is there a reason you care about linear space rather than polynomial space?

Comment: @SureshVenkat Even easier, TQBF is in SPACE(n).

Comment: @usul I do care about linear space in particular, because I'm trying to use this language I get to prove something about a different linear-space-bounded class.

Comment: ${}$#2 $\; \implies \;$ $L \not\in \operatorname{TIME}(n^k) \;\;$, $\;\;$ so you can simplify #1. $\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer good point.

Comment: If people conjecture ETH then obviously they also conjecture that TQBF requires exponential time. If you are among if that is a plausible conjecture them the answer is yes. If you are asking if that has a name then I think the answer is no. It seems to me what you want to know is if it is plausible to conjecture that TQBF requires exponential time but SAT doesn't.

Comment: @Kaveh Moreover, do we know anything about how much weaker the conjecture that TQBF requires exponential time is than ETH? Or if you don't want to talk about TQBF, might there be an even weaker assumption that *some* linear space language requires exponential time, even if neither TQBF nor SAT do?

Comment: @Kaveh : $\;\;\;$ I think you confused size-of-an-instance with number-of-variables-in-an-instance. $\:$ If no, now can one show that ETH implies the existence of a language as described above? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Kaveh : $\;\;\;$ What coding is that achieved in? $\:$ In the only coding I'm aware of, the size is proportional to num_of_vars*log(num_of_vars). $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Kaveh : $\;\;\;$ How is it shown that "ETH implies that 3SAT requires $2^{\Omega(n)}$ time where $n$ is the size of the input"? $\:$ I believe the _definition_ of ETH specifies that $n$ is the number of variables; do you disagree with that? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Ricky, OK, you are right. Now I am not sure if Jeremy really needs $2^{\Omega(n)}$ or if $2^{\Omega(n / \lg n)}$ is enough.